# How to make a Lightning Component in a Lightning record page visible to a subset of users?

Tags: lightning, filters, visibility, component

I would like a single Lightning Record Page to have 2 components, each visible only to a specific set of users. There are a few users identified as 'beta testers' and one version of the component should be made visible to these users, which others will view the other users will see a different version.

From what I have tried so far, component filters have CONTAINS, EQUAL and NOT EQUAL condition. Can someone suggest a way to do this?

-- Update (30/04/2019) --
I have used filter logic to handle this. Didn't realise there is an option to use NOT operator in the filter logic!

Comment: Do they all have the same profile? What attributes differentiate them from one another other than their username or userId? Can you make them members of a Group or create a permission set?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same profile and there's no other differentiator field on their record. However, I can make them members of a group/assign a permission set manually.

Comment: The permission set/group would seem to me to be the most obvious and simplest solution to your issue.

Comment: I suggest you to change the title of your question. Is a bit misleading.

Comment: @gvgramazio - Thank you for your suggestion. Mind telling me what's misleading? Will change the title accordingly.

Comment: I would opt for something like ‘how to make a lightning component in a lightning page visible to a subset of users only?’. This allows also answers that don’t involve setting the visibility at page level but at component level.

Comment: By the way, I also agree with the group/permission set idea, even more if this is the only difference they have with normal users. It’s simple and also easily maintainable.

Comment: gvgramazio, crmprogdev - Thank you for your suggestions. Will the permission/group be a controlling field to hide the other component for the 'beta tester' users as well? My initial dirty approach was to filter by username to display, but this did not work to hide the other component (which is why I asked for help to know if there is a 'NOT' condition that I can use in the filter). Please excuse if it was confusing.

Comment: I've used filter logic to do this. Didn't realise there is an option to use NOT operator in the filter logic!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind add to the User object, just create a custom checkbox field on the User called `Beta Tester` and then you could conditionally show components on the page based on this true/false checkbox.